# How to append string representation of a specified object to a instance

Tags: c#

I have a code like this:

```
StringBuilder systemCondition = new StringBuilder();
systemCondition.Append("^(");
systemCondition.Append(Regex.Escape(this.Class));
systemCondition.Append(" : ");
systemCondition.Append(Regex.Escape(this.Instance));
systemCondition.Append(")$");
m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter = systemCondition.ToString();
```

Can any body tell me whats wrong here?
Then what about this code

Comment: You are returning whole different stuff, that is why you see different string. You didn't optimize the code, you changed the logic itself.

Comment: ricky - what? Your last comment didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want more elegant code in one line, why not this?

```
m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter = string.Format("^({0} : {1})$", Regex.Escape(this.Class), Regex.Escape(this.Instance));
```

Comment: What about the code? Don't know, you didn't really ask any question. String is totally fine, `StringBuilder` should be used only when you append to the string in a loop or something like that.

Comment: ricky throwing code at us won't help. You have to **explain** what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Comments are not meant for code. Please add it to your question.